# How do I use the datepart function in combination with a count function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to return all the results where a month from one date is exactly 1 month after another.
Like this:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Column A date:          Column B date:  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 11/20/2019               12/1/2019      ║
║ 8/5/2019                 9/1/2019       ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I get how to use the datepart function but how could I use it in conjunction with something to check if it's 1 month after? Would I use a count function?

this is what I have so far:

```
and datepart("m", oe.text_13_eff_date)
```

Comment: [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

Comment: Are the examples you show positives or negatives? "Exactly 1 month after" implies that those are both `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for the difference in months i.e. February - January = 1 then you can use

```
and    DATEPART(m,firstdate)-DATEPART(m,seconddate) = 1
```

actually @ Eric Brandt comment is a much better answer

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, firstdate, seconddate) = 1
```

If you want a true month i.e feb 24th - jan 24th = 1 then like @Tomalak has said it would be more like.

```
 and   dateadd(m,1,seconddate) = firstdate
```

Comment: Your first example will return `TRUE` for `2020-01-01` and `2019-02-01`. Not sure if that's the intention.

Comment: You already have an accepted answer, so I'm not posting, but I think what the OP is really after here is `DATEDIFF(MONTH, firstdate, seconddate) = 1`. Handles the year component for you.

Comment: Thanks, your first answer was what I was looking for. I was making that more complicated than it needed to be haha.

Comment: @Eric Brandt absolutely you are correct that is a much better approach, I added it to the answer and tried to clean up my comments best I could

Comment: @Gratzy, it's rough when the question is open to interpretation. You had two of the three possibilities covered! :)